# Regular expression sequence starting with a number followed by uppercase HMS

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression to match a sequence that starts with a number `[0-9]` followed by only **one** uppercase `[HMS]`.

For example the following should match, `10H`, `10H20M`, `10H20M9S`, `20M`, `5H6S`. Lowercase letters are not allowed. Only `H`,`M`,`S` after any number between `[0-9]`.

These should fail ( `3Y5M`, `5H4F`, `10H6MM` ).

I tried this but it doesn't work :(

```
^[0-9][HMS]$/
```

Comment: Maybe `^\d+H(\d+M)?(\d+S)?$` / `^\d+H(?:\d+M)?(?:\d+S)?$`

Comment: Your regexp only only matches one number followed by 1 uppercase, not a sequence of them.

Comment: Does it have to be in the order  hours-minutes-seconds? Or can it be `10M1H`?

Comment: Perhaps `^(\d+[HMS])+$`

Comment: It sounds like this is an XY problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem - what's the actual problem you seek to solve?

Comment: `\b(?:[0-9]{1,2}[HMS])+\b`

Comment: ```^(\d+[HMS])+$``` , ```\b(?:[0-9]{1,2}[HMS])+\b```, Thank you but these won't work as they allow duplicate time units. ```5M5M``` would fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?!$)(?:(\d+)H)?(?:(\d+)M)?(?:(\d+)S)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7X00Uc/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!$)` - the string can't be empty
- `(?:(\d+)H)?` - an optional group matching one or more digits  (captured into Group 1) and then an `H` char
- `(?:(\d+)M)?` - an optional group matching one or more digits  (captured into Group 2) and then an `M` char
- `(?:(\d+)S)?` - an optional group matching one or more digits  (captured into Group 3) and then an `S` char
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: This is actually better than what I was thinking. I had other checks on the backend that ordered the units in `HMS`, but this Regex does it all up front and really simplifies my code. Thanks for the detailed breakdown of what everything means. This handles every edge case.